# Android, Xamarin: Build TextView with mulitiple fonts (bold, regular)

Tags: c#, android

I have a textview that is supposed to look somewhat like this:

"You are best in **SPORTS**"

Both in the same font.
Sport is supposed to be BLACK, the rest is supposed to be greyish.

I have found alot about spannable strings, but I just couldnt get this to work in xamarin (c#).

Also, this didnt include setting one part bold then another regular.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **FormattedString**

```
var labelFormatted = new Label ();
var fs = new FormattedString ();
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text="Red, ", ForegroundColor = Color.Red, FontSize = 20, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic });
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text=" blue, ", ForegroundColor = Color.Blue, FontSize = 32 });
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text=" and green!", ForegroundColor = Color.Green, FontSize = 12 });
labelFormatted.FormattedText = fs;
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks, but ther problem is, I cannot put this into the textview. It says (cannot convert string formattedstring) ...

Comment: try `toString()` method for casting.

Comment: im getting: System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it. even tho i do init it ...